# i want hyperlink address from below code

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Here is some example code. Node structure of iframe contents are like in this manner.

```
 <iframe>
  <div class="eod-topbox">
  <a href="some link">dfdf</a>
  <div id="something">
     <img src="">
  </div>
 </div>
 </iframe>
```

I am trying in this manner.Please give any useful answer so i can get hyperlink address from eod topbox class from iframe.

```
 function getElement(){
     var iBody = $("#frametest").contents().find(".eod-topbox").html();
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHtml=iBody;
     alert(iBody);
 }
```

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery and DOM?

Comment: later i want to save these data to database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need `link` `href` attribute, try this:

```
function getElement(){
     var $link = $("#frametest").contents().find(".eod-topbox").children('a').first();
     alert($link.attr('href'));
 }
```

Comment: i already added bracket but alert is showing null or object object thanks